# Separate a column into 2 columns at the last specific character in R (appearing different times)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
id <-c("1","2","3")
col <- c("hello, my 5 year old son is joe, 76","hello world, 55","can't say I didn't, 3")
```

```
df <- data.frame(id,col)
```

I am hoping to divide col into only two columns, one that takes only the numbers after the comma (but no other number) and the other takes the response. So my desired output is:

```
id     text                             nunber
1     hello, my 5 year old son is joe.  76
2     hello world                       55
3     can't say I didn't                3
```

I've tried:

```
separate(col, into=c("text","number"), ",(?=[^_]+$)")
```

but it obviously cuts the text with the comma before.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

using `extract`:

```
df %>% extract(col = 'col', into=c("text","number"), regex = '(.*),\\s(\\d+$)')
  id                             text number
1  1 hellow, my 5 year old son is joe     76
2  2                      hello world     55
3  3               can't say I didn't      3
```

Comment: Thanks - it just created to na columns. Maybe the texts are longer?

Comment: @chagag, is your data different to what your sample data shows?

Comment: Its a bit longer and may include different punctuations.

Comment: @chagag, ok, because I mentioned `,` in the regex, it's looking for a comma as the last separator just before the ending number.

Comment: the last character before the number is always a comma, just not sure what comes before.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `separate` with a regex lookaround to match the `,` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) and one or more digits at the end (`$`) of the string inside the lookaround

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    separate(col, into = c('text', 'number'), ',\\s*(?=[0-9]+$)', convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 id                             text number
1  1 hellow, my 5 year old son is joe     76
2  2                      hello world     55
3  3               can't say I didn't      3
```

Comment: Thanks! Got this error - Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` . Maybe because some texts are longer?

Comment: @chagag is this based on the same example you posted as I can't reproduce it.   Also, the message you mentioned is not an error, but just a warning

Comment: Any clue how to modify if there isn't space  between the text and the comma? Thanks

Comment: @chagag just change it to `\\s*` updated.  ie. zero or more spaces